# React redux toolkit returning "t is not a function. (In 't(i,c)', 't' is an instance of Object)" when trying to covert createStore to configureStore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to convert

> react redux

to its counterpart

> react redux toolkit

but i kept running into this problem

> t is not a function. (In 't(i,c)', 't' is an instance of Object)

And I don't really understand what it means.
This is the configureStore.js

```
    import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {  persistStore,  persistReducer,  FLUSH,  REHYDRATE,  PAUSE,  PERSIST,  PURGE,  REGISTER,} from 'redux-persist'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

//import sagas from 'app/sagas';
import {
  loginReducer,
  paymentReducer,
  signupReducer
} from '../reducer';

const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: ['loadingReducer'],
  debug: true, //to get useful logging
};

const middleware = [];
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

middleware.push(sagaMiddleware);

if (__DEV__) {
  middleware.push(createLogger());
}
const reducers = persistReducer(config, {reducer:{
    loginReducer,
    signupReducer,
    paymentReducer
  }})

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducers,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
      thunk: false,
      ...middleware
    }),
})

let persistor = persistStore(store);
const myStore = () => {
  return { persistor, store };
};

export default myStore
//sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);
/*import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {},
})
```

while this is

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'
import { DefaultTheme, Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Navigator from './app/navigation';
import myStore from './app/store/configureStore';
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';
enableScreens();

const { persistor, store } = myStore();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  roundness: 2,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    // primary: '#3498db',
    // accent: '#f1c40f',
  },
};

export default function Entrypoint() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
          <Navigator />
        </PaperProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I don't know where the problem is but

1. I'm quite sure the problem is in the configureStore script
2. How do I solve this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when moving from Redux to Redux Toolkit. It seems that removing the redux and react-redux packages before installing Redux Toolkit fixed the issue I was having (`o.configureStore is not a function`).

Also, your middleware is not in line with how the documentation writes it, it should be:

```js
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
      thunk: false
    })
    .concat(middleware)
```

I didn't use `persist-redux` nor Redux Saga though, maybe there's something else.